# React - how call function parent from grandchild

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I take photo to demonstrate, you may look at it:

[image: react]

My parent component is 1, grand child component place at 3, at 2 I can do some stuff because they is parent-child but I can't call function of 1 when I look from 3, any your interest, thanks!

Comment: You can either pass the function through your second component or use react context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Sorry if you had waiting response, sincerely I thought prop drilling as soon as I been stuck however I missing some clue to make it seamlessly, here my model:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass props from child to grandchild

here is an example (i use react native)

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: 'original state'
    }
  }
  stateUpdate(data) {
    this.setState({result:data})
  }

  render() {
  return  (
    <View>
      <Text>parent state: {this.state.result}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.stateUpdate('original state')}
        title="original state"
        color="darkgreen"
      />
      <Child data={this.state.result} updateState={(data) => this.stateUpdate(data)} />
    </View>
    )
  }
 }
```

Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GrandChild from './GrandChild';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
  return  (
    <View>
        <Text style={{height:20}} />
        <Text>child prop: {this.props.data}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.updateState('Changed from Child')}
          title="change parent state"
          color="#841584"
        />
        <GrandChild data={this.props.data} updateParent={(data) => this.props.updateState(data)} />
    </View>
    )
  }
 }
```

GrandChild.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class GrandChild extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
      return  (
        <View>
            <Text style={{height:20}} />
            <Text>GrandChild prop: {this.props.data}</Text>
            <Button
              onPress={() => this.props.updateParent('change from GrandChild')}
              title="change parent state"
              color="darkblue"
            />
        </View>
    )
  }
 }
```

here is a snack
https://snack.expo.io/GsuAf65kK

or use context api.

hope it help.

Comment: About above comment, I press Enter when it not finish, this is snippet which I want talk about // GrandChild.js 
class GrandChild extends Component { 
return <Button onPress={this.props.callChild}  
} 

//Child.js 
import GrandChild 
class Child extends Component { 
return <GrandChild callChild={this.props.callParent}/> 
} 

//Parent.js 
class Parent extends Component { 
doSomething = () => {...} 
return <Child callParent={this.doSomething} 
} 

it not work ...if you still not figure out, I'l give more idea, respect!